# Prompted for a username and password in Chrome for a JQuery Kendo dataSource request

Tags: iis-7, authorization, kendo-datasource

When I try to access a Kendo datasource like this:

```
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: constructServerActionUrl(reportsController, getVisitorsAction),
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    start: $("#report-bar-start").val(),
                    end: $("#report-bar-end").val()
                }
            }
        }
```

I get prompted for a username and password in chrome when there's an attempt to access the datasource. This doesn't happen on the staging and live servers, only on local and test. I've tried:

- Enabling anonymous access in IIS
- Enabling Windows Authentication in IIS
- Giving the IUSR account read access to all files in the application
- Setting the app pool identity to an administrator account
- Stopping and starting IIS

Although this is clearly an IIS configuration issue, I'm wondering if there's any way I can guarantee this issue to never occur, for example by specifying a 'no authorization' header before the datasource request is made, within the 'read' property of the dataSource. Something like this (which doesn't work):

```
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'None');
```

Alternatively, what other IIS setting may be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that my controller is called 'reports', which unbelievably clashes with SQL server reporting services if it happens to be running on the machine. I changed the controller name and everything now works.